# Не появляется фото в HTML при его выводе. - Django

Tags: python, django

У меня проблема с редактированием фото. Проблема в том, что при выводе фото в HTML, фото не появляется,а просто пустое поле `Выберите фото.` и всё.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import  ResizeToFill
class Announcement(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table='announcements'

    title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone_num=models.IntegerField()
    price=models.IntegerField()
    first_image_original=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    first_image_big = ImageSpecField(source='first_image_original',
                                 processors=[ResizeToFill(150, 75)],
                                 format='JPEG',
                                 options={'quality': 90})

    first_image_middle = ImageSpecField(source='first_image_original',
                                 processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                 format='JPEG',
                                 options={'quality': 90})

    first_image_small = ImageSpecField(source='first_image_original',
                                 processors=[ResizeToFill(75, 35)],
                                 format='JPEG',
                                 options={'quality': 90})
```

views.py:

```
def editads(request, announcement_id):
v=get_object_or_404(Announcement, pk=announcement_id)
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.get('First_image_original', False):
    ads=Announcement.objects.get(pk=announcement_id)
    ads.title=request.POST.get('Title')
    ads.description=request.POST.get('Description')
    ads.phone_num=request.POST.get('Phone_num')
    ads.price=request.POST.get('Price')
    ads.first_image_original=request.FILES.get('First_image_original')
    ads.save()
    return redirect('/reklama/ads_detail/'+str(announcement_id)+'/')
else:
    return render(request, 'account/edit_ads.html',{'dataAnnouncement':v })
```

html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Edit </h1>
<form action="/reklama/edit_ads/{{ dataAnnouncement.id }}/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table cellpadding="10" align="center">
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ dataAnnouncement.id }}" name="Announcement_id">
            <td>Title</td>
                <td><input type="text" required name="Title" value="{{dataAnnouncement.title}}" size="26"></td>
            <td>Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" required name="Description" value="{{dataAnnouncement.description}}" size="26"></td>
            <td>Phone_num</td>
                <td><input type="text" required name="Phone_num" value="{{dataAnnouncement.phone_num}}" size="26"></td>
            <td>price</td>
                <td><input type="text" required name="Price"  value="{{dataAnnouncement.price}}" size="26"></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First_image_original</td>
                <td><p><input type="file" name="First_image_original" value="{{ dataAnnouncement.first_image_original}}"></p></td>
        </tr>

    <!--<input type="hidden" value = "{{ ads.id }}"> -->
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save changes"></p>
</form>
<h3>{{message}}</h3>
<h3>{{error}}</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Почему Вы не используете form API?

Comment: хотелось без form  посмотреть на все это.

Comment: помогите чем поправлять вопрос